# Mod Rewrite change extention of a page

Tags: apache, mod-rewrite

i want to mod rewrite change extension of any page to what i want.

for ex. i want change `index.php` to `index.abc`

is it possible with mod rewrite?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^(.*)\.abc$ $1.php
```

that should change all of your pages from `.PHP` to `.ABC`